# I receive error message on my rss feed says no data was found

Tags: magento-1.7, javascript

I'm using rss feed on my website. Over suddenly I get an error message that says

```
"Error! Error! No data was found for RSS feed or no items available for this feed"
```

I searched for this issue and I notice there are a lot of websites that have this issue but what I couldn't find is the solution. Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Magpie RSS and not Magento.

Answer (score 0):

This error is **specific to Magpie RSS** class which is off-topic for this forum.

A note: while you may be using Magpie for your RSS it seems to me **this is redundant** because Magento is built on Zend, which has an RSS handler:

```
$channel = new Zend_Feed_Rss('http://rss.example.com/channelName');
```

Your specific error may point to the RSS feed being invalid, though, and using Zend will not rectify this error for you. However, it will throw a `Zend_Feed_Exception` if invalid XML is encountered, which may help you to debug.

---

More info on Zend Feed:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html